# How do I not allow access to the home page without sign-in?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, web

I'm new in nodeJs, so I prepared a sign in page with the database and it works normally.
Now I have prepared a home page, but I notice that the client can access the home page directly without connection in his account by this link http://127.0.0.1:5500/public/Home.html
So what should I learn or should I do?
Any examples or propositions are welcome.

Comment: i use nodejs exppressJS bootstrapV4 and mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use a middleware to check the user is logged in or not.

for example

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Auth = require('../middleware/auth');//require the Auth middleware
 

router.get('/',Auth,async(req,res)=>{
       //here ^^^^^
  //your code...

})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need authentication

One of the easy and secure way is to user JSON Web Token (JWT)

[here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jwt-authentication-with-node-js/)